# Assign button text dynamically via a loop

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am trying to assign button controls text dynamically by using a loop like the following:

```
int ButtonNumber = 1;

while (ButtonNumber < 10)
{
    //WHAT TO DO HERE!?
    ButtonNumber++;
}
```

I wanna avoid the following:

```
button1.Text = "";
button2.Text = "";
button3.Text = "";
button4.Text = "";
button5.Text = "";
button6.Text = "";
button7.Text = "";
button8.Text = "";
button9.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ideally, don't have `button1`, `button2` etc as variables in the first place. Have a collection (e.g. a `List<Button>`):

```
private List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
```

(EDIT: You'd need to populate this somewhere, of course...)

then to update the text later:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)
{
    buttons[i].Text = "I'm button " + i;
}
```

This doesn't play terribly nicely with the designer, unfortunately.

You *can* fetch a control by ID, but personally I try not to do that. If you *really* want to:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Control control = Controls["button" + i];
    control.Text = "I'm button " + i;
}
```

Comment: Don't you also need to instantiate each Button object? Also add them to the list.

Comment: Why do you NOT recommend the use of fetching the control by ID?
It works like a charm!?

Comment: @Alex: You've got a *collection* of buttons, right? How do you deal with collections *everywhere else in code*? You use a collection class. Why should the UI be any different? The only difference here is the designer not really understanding the idea of a collection of controls :(

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of buttons:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
   buttons[i] = new Button();
   buttons[i].Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [this.Controls.Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) to locate a named control in WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this simply, assuming if you have all buttons in your form

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if (c is Button)
                {
                    c.Text = "MyButton" + (c.TabIndex + 1);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

// try this

```
         Button btn;
         for (int n_i = 0; n_i < 10; n_i++)
            {
            btn = (Button)Controls.Find("button" + n_i,true)[0];
            btn.Text = "";
            }
```